# Combinatorics with dices

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say that we play dice **30** times.

How many ways can I play the dice **30** times and the sum of all throws is 105.
I started by subtracting 30 to 105, since at least the result in every throw is '1'  and then I use the **Bars and Stars Method** to distribute the remaining **75** points in **30** boxes and I get (104,75). Now I need to subtract the cases whenever those boxes get more points than 5.

I am supposed to use the **Principle Of Inclusion and Exclusion** somewhere, but I don't know how to use it. I am in my 1st year at college, so I would really appreciate if you could tell me how to think when faced with this kind of problems.

Answer (score 1):

The way to face this problems is as follows. You count all possibilities and then subtract the ones you do not like. As you have suggested. The problem is **how** you subtract them. So the way to think about this is assume the $i-$th dice  gives you more than $6$ so you can create that property. First abstract your problem to be the following
$$A=\{(d_1,\cdots ,d_{30}):\sum _{i=1}^{30}d_i=105, \, 1\leq d_i\leq 6\},$$
so you apply your very smart observation by doing $c_i=d_i-1$ to get a set
$$B=\{(c_1,\cdots ,c_{30}):\sum _{i=1}^{30}c_i=105-30=75, \, 0\leq c_i\leq 5\}.$$
that assignment is a bijection, so $|A|=|B|.$
Now consider $B_j=\{(c_1,\cdots , c_{30}):\sum _{i=1}^{30}c_i=75,\, c_j>5\},$
because this is **exactly** the properties that you do not want, you want to count all possibilities (without any single restriction) and then take out the sequences that lie inside any of the $B_j.$ So you want
$$\left |\text{All}\setminus \bigcup _{i=1}^{30}B_i\right |=\left |\text{All}\right |- \left | \bigcup _{i=1}^{30}B_i\right |.$$
By using stars and bars you can compute All.
Now you focus in what happens with the $B_j'$s Notice that using your idea, you can set $e_j = c_j-6$ because you know that in $B_j$ $c_j>5$ so $e_j\geq 0,$ so again, using stars and bars you can get your result.
Then you try to do it for two sets say $n\neq m$ you want to compute
$$\left | B_n\bigcap B_m \right |,$$ notice that it is analogous to the last one but here you are doing $e_n = c_n-6$ **and** $e_m=c_m-6.$ If you notice, this will not depend on $n$ or $m,$ but **just in the fact** that you choosed two. This is called **homogeneous,** so whenever you are doing the PIE, you will just have to consider $\binom{30}{2}|B_1\cap B_2|=\sum _{1\leq i<j\leq 30}|B_i\cap B_j|.$
Can you get then the formula?

Comment: Thanks for replying, 'ej' in this case stands for...?

Comment: $e_j=c_j-6,$ meaning from the variable you know that surpasses $5$ you take $6$ to recenter it at $0.$